# Symfony: How to handle common request scope data

Tags: symfony, event-handling, twig, requestscope

I'm migrating a legacy PHP project (pre-OO) to Symfony2. On every request I have to:

- compute some dynamic data (depending on the current date and/or some request parameter)
- use that data (multiple times!) in the rendered response.

A naive approach would be:

- At the start of every controller method, call some global helper function to compute the data.
- At the end of every controller method, pass the data as a parameter to the twig template.

Sounds tedious. Maybe it would be better to:

- Create a subscriber for request events that computes the data when a request comes in and provides access to it via getter methods.
- Define that subscriber/service as a global twig variable in `config.yml`.
- In twig templates, call the getter methods on that service as needed.

Is that viable? 
In particular, are the twig variable/service and the subscriber always identical? Or could the service be a newly created instance?

Is this some sort of misuse? Or is there an officially recommended way for such a use case?

**EDIT** The data is not only needed in every twig template but in some controllers, too.

Comment: If you only need this information in twig templates then just create a twig extension and add your getters there.  That eliminates the need for a subscriber.  I would suggest taking the time to see if you really need this sort of data.  I know you are dealing with a legacy app but there may be better designs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this information is also needed in some controllers. Edited my question accordingly.

Comment: In which case, a Subscriber is your starting point.  Not a big fan of having a bunch of global data so be careful.  Globals can make your code difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a specific method in every Controller-Action would really be a bad solution. Your solution to use a subscriber isn't perfect either.

Without knowing your use-case in detail it´s hard to find a suitable way.
Maybe one approach would be to write a Twig-Extension and injecting a Service into this Extension. The Service would get the Request-Stack via Dependency-Injection and compute the relevant Data. You could then access this data "on demand" through the Twig-Extension during the rendering.
Another approach could be using sub-requests during the rendering ([Symfony: How to handle common request scope data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360034/symfony-how-to-handle-common-request-scope-data))

Maybe these tips already helped you a bit. Otherwise let me know more details, where / how you need the data during the rendering.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the dynamic data will be needed in some controllers, too...
What are your objections to subscribers?

Comment: I dont understand how you would pass the data from your subscriber into your controllers / rendering process. The only way I can imagine is using global vars or something like that. And that's definitely a bad solution.

Comment: If you want to access that data in your controllers, too, I would recommend using a central service and injecting the request-stack into it, as described above. Than simply use that service in your controllers and your twig-extension. The calculations for that data can be done on demand if accessed and if needed it can also be cached quite easily.

Comment: Ah! Just looked up [request_stack](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container/request.html) and think it's better than my subscriber. Will try that. Thanks!